# Jquery code doesn't work after paging?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, paging, datapager

i have written below code in my content page which has listview and datapager

```
    <asp:Content ID="content2" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <link href="../js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js")%>'type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function () { 
   $(".fancyYoutube").fancybox({ 
             'transitionIn': 'elastic',
             'transitionOut': 'fade',
             'width': 680,
             'height': 495,
             'type': 'swf'
             }); 
            });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

This works fine.. but when i do paging then code written doesn't work.

I could see that in visual studio one file is created 'Jscript-window script block'. and code written

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$BodyContent$lvEnglishMovieList$dpgGallery$ctl01$ctl01','')
```

What does this mean??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(showtrailer);
        showtrailer();
    });
    function showtrailer() {
        $(".fancyYoutube").fancybox({
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'fade',
            'width': 680,
            'height': 495,
            'type': 'swf'
        });
    }
</script>
```

My listview was inside the update panel becuase of which i had to write these code. Got help from asp.net forum and the link is
[HERE](http://forums.asp.net/t/1682030.aspx/1?Jquery%20blocked%20while%20paging%20with%20DataPager%20)

Answer (score 1):

If your paging is asynchronous, the newly fetched DOM elements won't be captured by `$(".fancyYoutube")` as this only runs once on DOMready. You can create a more generic event handler that works with dynamically added elements by using the `.delegate()` method instead.

*EDIT*

In fact, looking again, the `.delegate()` method probably wouldn't work, as the `.fancybox()` function is not an event. In that case, you should find the callback function that is executed when paging completes (this will be the function that takes the new AJAX response and injects it into the DOM), and just make another call to `.fancybox()`, passing in the AJAX response HTML.

Can you post your pagination code? I could probably help you more clearly!

Comment: I am kind of new to jquery. can you please help me with the code?

Comment: i have used datapager control in asp.net.will post the html code as well as C# code too..

Comment: Oh really? The Datapager control itself doesn't appear to use any AJAX postbacks - I've never used it but the documentation suggests it's a full page reload, in which case your javascript SHOULD run fine. Is the ListView inside an Ajax update panel?

Comment: Hi Chris..my listview was inside the update panel...posted my code working code below. Thanks for sharing information. :-)

Answer (score 0):

ObjectDatasource code

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjHindiList" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllList"
                TypeName="Movie.Repositories.MovieDetailRepository" 
                OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Hindi" Name="movielanguage" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

now listview code with datapager in it.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" DataKeyNames="MovieId" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="ObjHindiMovieList" onitemcreated="ListView1_ItemCreated" 
                onitemdatabound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" EnableViewState="false">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table class="AllMovieList">
                        <tbody class="tablebody">
                            <tr id="itemplaceholder" runat="server" class="trd">
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <div class="CustomDataPager">
                                        <asp:DataPager ID="dpgGallery" PagedControlID="ListView1" runat="server" PageSize="10">
                                            <Fields>
                                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonCssClass="command" FirstPageText="« Previous" PreviousPageText="« Previous"
                                                    RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="false" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                                    ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowNextPageButton="false" RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="False" />
                                                <asp:NumericPagerField CurrentPageLabelCssClass="current" NextPreviousButtonCssClass="next"
                                                    RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="False" />
                                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonCssClass="command" LastPageText="›" NextPageText="Next »"
                                                    RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="false" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false"
                                                    ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowNextPageButton="true" RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="False" />
                                            </Fields>
                                        </asp:DataPager>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr class="trd">
                        <td valign="top" style="width: 100px">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("MovieThumbNailImageUrl")%>' runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" style="width: 600px">
                            <table class="InnerList">
                                <tr class="InnerTrRow">
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <div style="float: left">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblmovieName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MovieName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="float: right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ReleaseDate","{0:dd-MMM-yy}")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <asp:LinkButton CssClass="linkbutton" ID="lnkabout" runat="server" OnClick="lnkabout_Click" Text="About Movie"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp|
                                        <asp:LinkButton CssClass="linkbutton" ID="lnkGallery" runat="server" Text="Photos"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp|
                                        <a class="fancyYoutube" href='<%#Eval("TrailerUrl") %>'>View Trailer</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td>
                                        <b>Director</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDirector" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Director") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                        <b>Producer</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Producer") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td>
                                        <b>Staring</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblstarring" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Cast") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                    <tr style="width: 600px">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div style="border-top: solid 1px #FFF; width: 100%">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

and in code behind i have not written anything for paging.